# Using multiple Count in a Single Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query below that i wanna return total number of critical & warning alerts of a day,but problem i have is that when i do it for range of days it's adding the critical alerts of the date specified

```
SELECT alertDate as "Alert Date",
    (SELECT COUNT(alertType) FROM alerts WHERE alertDate BETWEEN '2016/02/15' AND '2016/02/16' AND UPPER(alertType)='CRITICAL') as Critical,
    (SELECT COUNT(alertType) FROM alerts WHERE alertDate BETWEEN '2016/02/15' AND '2016/02/16' AND UPPER(alertType)='WARNING') as Warning
FROM alerts
where alertDate BETWEEN '2016/02/15' AND '2016/02/16'
GROUP BY alertDate;
```

tried the code above but apparently i can't add "group by" clause inside a sub-query,which i think is the problem,Please any help on how i can go about this...

Comment: could you please provide us with some expected result which is not addressed by your query?

Comment: Can you please pick either MySQL **or** SQL Server? They are both very different...

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: i'm sorry,i'm using sqlserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation -- the `case` goes inside the aggregation function.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT alertDate as AlertDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(alertType) = 'CRITICAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Critical,
       SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(alertType) = 'WARNING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WARNING
FROM alerts a
WHERE alertDate BETWEEN '2016-02-15' AND '2016-02-16'
GROUP BY alertDate;
```

If you are using MySQL, you can shorted this to:

```
SELECT alertDate as AlertDate,
       SUM(UPPER(alertType) = 'CRITICAL') as Critical,
       SUM(UPPER(alertType) = 'WARNING') as Warning
FROM alerts a
WHERE alertDate BETWEEN '2016-02-15' AND '2016-02-16'
GROUP BY alertDate;
```

Note a couple other changes:

- No subselects are necessary.
- I removed the space from `AlertDate`.  I'm just not a fan of column aliases that need to be escaped.
- I replaced the `/` with `-` in the date literals -- the hyphens are ISO 8601 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sum(case) for this:

```
SELECT alertDate as "Alert Date",
    sum(case when UPPER(alertType)='CRITICAL' then 1 end) as Critical,
    sum(case when UPPER(alertType)='WARNING' then 1 end) as Warning
FROM alerts
where alertDate BETWEEN '2016/02/15' AND '2016/02/16'
GROUP BY alertDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a conditional count like

```
SUM( case when alertDate BETWEEN '2016/02/15' AND '2016/02/16' 
     AND UPPER(alertType)='CRITICAL' then 1 else 0 end) as Critical,
```